# Sharepoint to Crawl Custom Visual WebPart

Tags: search-results

I have a page called `Support.aspx` with a custom visual webpart (using VS2012) which shows the content from a list.

I need a solution where if some one search the word in SharePoint search, the result should point to the `Support.aspx` page not the `dispform.aspx` or `allitems.aspx` of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one is easy, I am going to assume you're using SharePoint 2013, please let me know if this is not the case, what you need to do is put the support.aspx page as a promoted link.

1. Go to the site settings and click on "Search Query rules" under "Site collection administration".
2. Select your search result source you'd like to use
3. Click "New Query Rule"
4. Under query conditions put in all the keywords you'd like to hit the support page (Support, help, etc)
5. Next to actions click "Add promoted result"
6. Enter the url and title you'd like to display with this result.

This will always cause your page to get on top of the search results, regardless of what's crawled.

EDIT: As you're saying this is a public facing internet website and you want to disable access to the list views, please remember usually anonymous users are simply not allowed to visit these "system pages". It might be you turned this off for some functionality you needed to expose, but if you want to re enable the SharePoint lockdown mode. Go to the Site Collection features under Site Settings and find the following feature:

http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/Media/Windows-Live-Writer/SharePoint-2013-and-anonymous-users-acce_11220/image_3.png

This is a very intrusive option, if your application is not designed around it, you'll probably need to do some good testing before putting it online.

To change search results so the list views point to the support page. The easiest way would be to add a result type specifically for list views and create a display template for it. Within the display template you can modify the logic so it points to the support page instead of the listview directly.

To do this...

1. Go to your mastepage gallery and go into the folder "Display templates"
2. Follow through into the Search directory
3. Map this directory and copy the "item_default.html" file and rename it to "item_listview.html"
4. Modify this display template, follow the instructions of this: 
   http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1.aspx
   http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.be/2012/11/customizing-sharepoint-2013-search.html
   (This was a quick look, there might be better tutorials for this)
5. Once you're done and you'd like to test, go into "Result types" under "Site Collection administration" under "Site Settings"
6. In here, create a result type that points to "SharePoint List" and select your display template

Comment: Hi Christoffel Thanks for the comments, Basically this is public facing site. say there will be more the 100 pages. Is there any other way

Comment: This solution does not work for you?

Comment: Do you mean you have more than 100 different support pages?

Comment: Its not support page, different pages

Comment: Ah, right, now I understand, you want list views to point to the support.aspx page? Is there any reason why the list views are enabled for anonymous users? You don't want to disable this option completely?

Comment: Christoffel,This is public facing site. the Page "support" is not the list view, its a page in pages library. there are different content type in the page library with custom columns. support page is created with one of the contenttype which has custom webpart that will render the value from the support page metadata.

Comment: If this is a public facing site , why you need to show dispform and allitems in the search results , this has to be omitted first

Comment: Right, you can use a crawl rule in the search service application settings to remove all forms from the search result: Forms/*.aspx. Or you can use the search webpart property filter.

Comment: Thanks,  Forms/*.aspx is for document library, what about for List.

Comment: You'll have to do that manually for each view name. But the preferable and most robust solution is simply using the lockdown feature I described above. This will do the same thing as the crawl rules

Comment: If the solution works for you, be sure to mark my post as answer and or upvote if it's usefull. Thanks